# Inrush problem while using a isolated DC lab power supply

Tags: power-supply, grounding, test-equipment, leakage-current

I'm puzzled by an issue I've been observing during my testing of H-bridge buck converter.

I'm using 2 lab bench DC PSU such as E3630 (Keysigh)t to supply ISOLATED 5V to a driver.

When I power up the circuit and increase the input voltage of buck converter to 5V, I see a large input current drawn (>200mA) under no load condition.

I've tried to replace the DC PSU with other units that have been working well, but this problem doesn't get resolved. I only see this issue with the power supply.

One thing I noticed is, when I move the wire from the PSU to the bootstrap node or move the PSU, the leakage amount changes. It looks like the leakage decreases as PSU is placed far away from the device under test (DUT).

I do not understand why the wire placement between the DC PSU and DUT for bootstrap supply causes a large leakage from the input port of the buck converter (which are physically separated).
[image]
Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147452/discussion-on-question-by-penguineering-problem-with-using-a-lab-bench-dc-psu-fo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Please don't invalidate your question after it has been resolved. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with OP and some testing, the issue was confirmed.

What was the issue:
2 isolated power supply (or test instrument) were used with different reference (negative terminal) voltage. One is the ground and the other is an output signal (that is switch at 1MHz).

What happens:
The two reference seems to be floating(high impedance) one from the other, but this is only true in DC. When you increase the frequency, the reference terminal impedances gets lower (with the ground) and thus, current will flow from the reference (negative terminal) of the power supply to the ground. Any power source with an impedance relative to ground will create an undesirable circuit that will draw current or make your measurement fails.

When it happens:
Whenever you have many instrument with different reference (including oscilloscope, DMM, PCU, FGen) and any pulsed or AC circuit circuit. ie: A DMM in current mode on the high side or two power supply like in this case or an oscilloscope and a "floating" power supply.

How to prevent it:
Using handheld device (as DMM and oscilloscope) will solve it. Sometimes it is not possible, then, you need to rethink either your circuit or your bench setup.